# node not running after installation

Tags: node.js

I have installed the node.js. However, when I type `node --version`, it doesn't show anything. When I run the example.js file and go to localhost:8000, it seems the web server is not started at all. Any idea what might be wrong?

And I happen to have node and nodejs both on my computer.

Comment: What is your environment?

Comment: @aust it's linux mint 15

Comment: The console is empty when you type `node --version`? Do `whereis node`..., what does it report?

Comment: i am confusing, what are the differences between node and nodejs?? I had the latest version of nodejs, and when I try `whereis nodejs`,it gives "/usr/bin/nodejs /usr/lib/nodejs /usr/bin/X11/nodejs /usr/share/nodejs"

Comment: here is what I went through, first I installed node, but its a version 6, then i used the apt-get update and installed nodejs. When i try example.js, it doesn't work, I thought its because the path is pointing to the node version6, so i delete node and kept nodejs.

Comment: magically, it worked now...